# asp.net dropdown datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting Enumerable.Range to a List of Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694098/converting-enumerable-range-to-a-list-of-strings)

In ASP.NET how do I populate a drop down list and also include text for the default selected state?

For eg.

A drop down will contain: Enter day, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

```
ddlDayDropDown.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 31).ToList();
ddlDayDropDown.DataBind();
```

I can't add a "string" here.

Comment: what about this thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694098/converting-enumerable-range-to-a-list-of-strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ddlDayDropDown.DataSource = new string[] { "Enter day" }
  .Concat(Enumerable.Range(1, 31).Select(n => n.ToString()));
ddlDayDropDown.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 4):

Try `ddlDayDropDown.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Enter day"));`

Comment: ah, good thinking. better than mine