# Converting Enumerable.Range to a List of Strings

Tags: c#, linq

In Linq, how do convert Enumerable.Range(1, 31) to a List of strings?

Answer (score 37):

```
var list = Enumerable.Range(1, 31).Select(n => n.ToString()).ToList();
```

Comment: How much is the method Cast<string>() different (in terms of efficiency) ? 
var list = Enumerable.Range(1, 31).Cast<string>().ToList();

Answer (score 8):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> test;
        test = Enumerable.Range(1, 31).Select(n => n.ToString()).ToList();
        foreach (var item in test)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

This one print 31 lines for me :).

[image]

Comment: Since _n_ is not inherited from _IEnumerable_, _test_ is implemented by deferred execution.  The value returned by _GetRange_ is information required to perform the action.  The query is not **performed** until the object is enumerated by calling its _GetEnumerator_ method or by using _foreach_ .

Comment: @JimLahman, while you're right, in the code given, the query is executed in the `.ToList()` method, which comes before the `foreach`. At the time the `foreach` is executed, the list already contains all string values.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 string list = string.Join(string.Empty, Enumerable.Range(1, 31));
```

Sorry, I converted only to string.

```
var list = string.Join(",", Enumerable.Range(1, 31)).Split(',').ToList();
```

Comment: Joining and then splitting seems fairly inefficient to me. Why not just using a `Select`?